# Uable to load csv file using pandas into sql server

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, csv

I am new to pandas and I want to load a csv file into sql server.

I am able to read csv file. But while trying to load into sql server I am getting error as "No such column in target named as [index].While trying to run debugger in pycharm also, could see my to_SQL query as

```
INSERT INTO <target> (index,[0],[1],....) values (?,?,?..)
```

I have tried to remove index from dataframe but still issue exists. Kindly advise

Comment: Please give us minimal example of your csv file, the database schema and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try add the index=False option in your function? If you are using df.to_sql, it'll be something like:

```
df.to_sql(index=False,...)
```